# Implementing Search on Android Fragment

Tags: list, search, searchview

i have the following fragment, that displays a custom listiview, in which, every line has 2 items. A work in Japanese, and its meaning in portuguese. I am trying to implement a searh bar. The bar shows, but i dont know how to search and filter the list

The real list if much longer than that. I know i should have implemented the list inside a xml, but this was just easier.

`public class Dicionario extends ListFragment {`

```
    //ArrayList holds the data (as HashMaps) to load into the ListView
    ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> list = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();
    //SimpleAdapter does the work to load the data in to the ListView
    private SimpleAdapter sa;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_dicionario, container,
                false);


        ((MainActivity) getActivity()).setActionBarTitle(getString(R.string.dicionariotitle));


        Arrays.sort(termos, new ColumnComparator(0));


        HashMap<String,String> item;

        for(int i = 0; i< termos.length; i++){
            item = new HashMap<String,String>();
            item.put( "line1", termos[i][0]);
            item.put( "line2", termos[i][1]);
            list.add( item );
        }

        sa = new SimpleAdapter(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), list, R.layout.my_two_lines, new String[] { "line1","line2" }, new int[] {R.id.line_a, R.id.line_b});
        setListAdapter(sa);
        return rootView;
        //setListShown(true);




    }



    private String[][] termos =
            {{"DOJÔ","Área de Treinamento"},
                    {"JÔ-SEKI","Lugar onde se sentam as autoridades"},
                    {"REI-HÔ","Saudação"},
                    {"REI","Cumprimento"},
                    {"MOKUSO","Meditação (Fechar os olhos e manter  silêncio)"},
                    {"ZA-REI","Cumprimento ajoelhado"},
                    {"RITSU-REI","Cumprimento em pé"},
                    {"SHI-HAN","Mestre"},
                    {"SENSEI","Professor"},
                    {"SEITÔ","Aluno"},
                    {"DÔO-HAI","Colegas"},
                    {"NINTAI","Perserverança"},
                    {"DORYOKU","Esforço, empenho"},
                    {"HISSHYÔ","Ei de vencer"},
                    {"KATANÁ","Espada"},
                    {"DAITÔO","Espada Maior"},
                    {"SHÔOTÔO","Espada Menor"},
                    {"TANTÔO","Punhal"},
                    {"BOKKEN","Espada de Madeira"}

            };

@Override
public void onDestroyView() {
    super.onDestroyView();
    ButterKnife.reset(this);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I solved the broblem by using an activity, instead of a fragment. The following code works fine:

https://github.com/yurividal/iJudo/blob/master/app/src/main/java/br/pl/iJudo/ui/SearchableDictionary.java